# full text search across all the owl:NamedIndividual and return data

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web, ontology, protege

I'm using `Protege-5.0.0-beta-17` to develop an ontology and `apache-jena-fuseki-2.0.0` to host the ontology. It has following individuals. Background of this scenario is that there are policy individuals under `http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/local_policy`. Basically policies are type of the local_policies.

```xml
<!-- http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/policy1 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/policy1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/local_policy"/>
        <PolicyName rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">1.1.1</PolicyName>
        <PolicyResponsibility rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">CIO</PolicyResponsibility>
        <PolicyKeyword rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Information Security</PolicyKeyword>
        <PolicyMaturityLevel rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Interactive-Information</PolicyMaturityLevel>
        <PolicyConsulted rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">CERT</PolicyConsulted>
        <PolicyDesc rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">The relevant sections of Information Security Policy which has been published by government should be used for classifying organizational data and information.  The particular policies have been elaborated in &quot;Information assets classification and control&quot; of the Information Security (IS) policy  (http://www.government.lk/images/secPolicy/Asset_Classification_and_Control.doc). The Assistance of Computer Emergency Readiness Team (CERT) could be obtained for this purpose.</PolicyDesc>
        <apply rdf:resource="http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/focusArea1"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/policy2 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/policy2">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/local_policy"/>
        <PolicyName rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">2</PolicyName>
        <PolicyResponsibility rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">CIO</PolicyResponsibility>
        <PolicyKeyword rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Information Security</PolicyKeyword>
        <PolicyMaturityLevel rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Interactive-Information</PolicyMaturityLevel>
        <PolicyConsulted rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">CERT</PolicyConsulted>
        <PolicyDesc rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">The policies defined under the “Privacy and Citizen Information Protection” of the IS policy which have been  published by government should be implemented. The guidelines provided in the above section of IS policy could be accessed through  (http://www.government.lk/images/secPolicy/Privacy__Citizen_Information_Protection.doc). The assistance of CERT could be obtained for achieving this purpose.</PolicyDesc>
        <apply rdf:resource="http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/focusArea2"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    


    <!-- http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/policy3 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/policy3">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/local_policy"/>
        <PolicyName rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">3</PolicyName>
        <PolicyDesc rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">A matrix  could be defined for identifying all possible audience  and possible delivery channels of  organizational data/information. The template given in Annex 001 could be used for this purpose. (refer Annex 001 – Information/Data classification matrix)</PolicyDesc>
        <PolicyResponsibility rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">CIO</PolicyResponsibility>
        <PolicyConsulted rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">government</PolicyConsulted>
        <PolicyMaturityLevel rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Initial Infomration</PolicyMaturityLevel>
        <PolicyKeyword rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Service Delivery Channels</PolicyKeyword>
        <apply rdf:resource="http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/focusArea3"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
```

What I'm trying to do is query the ontology and fetch the these individuals. Also note that there are other individuals as well. Below is the query I'm using.

```
SELECT ?s
WHERE
{
  ?s ?p ?o 
  FILTER(REGEX(?o, "policy"))
}
```

But it does nt fetch the individuals as expected.

```
<http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/policy2>
<http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/policy1>
```

How can I do a full text search across all the `owl:NamedIndividual` and if there is a matching return the particular matching `owl:NamedIndividual` with all the data?

## Update

What I'm trying to do here is when a user type `policy` I want to fetch all the policies where it contains policy keyword. Let's assume that a user type `security` if so I want to fetch all the `owl:NamedIndividual` which contains keyword `security`. Also it should be type of local_policy as shown below.

```
<rdf:type rdf:resource="http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/local_policy"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "all the owl:NamedIndividual which contains keyword security."?  You mean that the (string of the) IRI of the named individual should contain "security"?  Or that some value of one of its properties should?

Comment: Yes, I mean all the individuals which are type of local_policy and within their body keyword/search-word should be in. As an example if I search for  `Information Security` 1st two individuals should appear. Not the last one. Even though last one is a type of local_policy, it does not contain the keyword `Information Security`. Just like a normal search.

Comment: "within their body" doesn't make sense in the context of RDF. There's no "body";  there are just triples of the form [subject predicate object].  Subjects are IRIs or blank nodes, predicates are always IRIs, and objects are IRIs, blank nodes, or literals.  You can convert literals and IRIs to strings and search in their content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to retrieve elements of type **http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/local_policy**, then you'll need to ask for those:

```sql
select * where {
  ?s rdf:type <http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/local_policy>
}
```

If you then want to ensure that they have some property with a value whose string representation contains the text policy, you'd add an appropriate filter.  E.g.:

```sql
select distinct ?s where {
  ?s ?p ?o ;
     a <http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/local_policy>
  filter contains(lcase(str(?o)),"security")
}
```

If you want to get all the properties and values of the individuals, just select the ?p and ?o variables as well:

```sql
select distinct ?s ?p ?o where {
  ?s ?p ?o ;
     a <http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/local_policy>
  filter contains(lcase(str(?o)),"security")
}
```

You could also use a construct query to get those triples back as a new model:

```sql
construct where {
  ?s ?p ?o ;
     a <http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/local_policy>
  filter contains(lcase(str(?o)),"security")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please see the updated question you can he a better idea what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Please see the comment. Thanks

Comment: @Techie See the update to my answer (I should have used "security" in the search, not "policy").  I think it does what you're looking for now.

Comment: I really appreciate the support. I think we are already there. Now it works just as I want except that it does not fetch the whole `NamedIndividual` such as all the elements inside `<owl:NamedIndividual></owl:NamedIndividual>` tag. What's the modification that is need to fetch all the details? `array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#17 (1) {
    ["s"]=>
    object(stdClass)#18 (2) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(3) "uri"
      ["value"]=>
      string(46) "http://mywebsite.com/module/ontologies/policy3"
    3
  }
}` Please note that result is correct. Just need to fetch the all the details

Comment: "the whole NamedIndividual" Again, RDF just has triples of the form [subject, predicate, object].  There's no notion of "the whole individual".  If you want to get all the predicates and values for which the individual is a subject, you can do that, though. See the latest update to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the support all the way